# Azure DevOps Pipeline not authenticating Az SQL powershell commands

Tags: authentication, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, pipeline, azure-powershell

When using the Azure CLI task within an Azure DevOps pipeline to run a powershell script as per the below:

```
$resourceGroupName = "rgname"
$serverName = "sqldbname"

$databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName

foreach ($database in $databases) {
    Write-Host "Deleting database $($database.DatabaseName)..."
    Remove-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName -DatabaseName $database.DatabaseName -Force
}
```

I'm seeing the below error thrown on the Get-AzSqlDatabase command:

> Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set
> up your Azure credentials. No certificate thumbprint or secret provided for the given service principal '***'.

I've also seen the same with the managed instance equivalent command 'Get-AzSqlInstanceDatabase'

What is the best way to authenticate these types of requests that does not require interaction? (given that it is being run within a pipeline as part of an automated process).

As an FYI the pipelines are being run on a self-hosted windows agent and the scripts within the job have been given access to the OAuth token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials. No certificate thumbprint or secret provided for the given service principal '***'.

Based on the error message, the Connect-AzAccount need to be run before the Get-AzSqlDatabase command.

To solve this issue, I suggest that you can change to use [Azure PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-powershell-v5?view=azure-pipelines).

It will automatically running the Connect-AzAccount command.

Here is an example:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'xx'
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     $resourceGroupName = "xxx"
     $serverName = "xxx"
     
     $databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServerName $serverName
     
     echo $databases
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this appears to be the easiest solution, I am now able to run powershell queries as required.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can accommodate that in Azure DevOps is to [create an Azure Resource Manager Service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops)

First, **you will need a SPN account**

- Using Powershell, connected to your Azure Subscription, execute the following command

`$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName ServicePrincipalName`

> The returned object contains the PasswordCredentials.SecretText property containing the generated password. Make sure that you store this value somewhere secure to authenticate with the service principal. Its value won't be displayed in the console output. If you lose the password, reset the service principal credentials.

- The following code allows you to export the secret:

`$sp.PasswordCredentials.SecretText`

> The default role for a password-based authentication service principal is Contributor. This role has full permissions to read and write to an Azure account. For information on managing role assignments, see [Manage service principal roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-11.3.0#manage-service-principal-roles).

- The object returned from **New-AzADServicePrincipal** contains the **Id** and **DisplayName** members, either of which can be used for sign in with the service principal.

Then, you will **Create a Service Connection in Azure DevOps**

- Sign in to your organization
  ([https://dev.azure.com/{yourorganization}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Byourorganization%7D)) and select your project.
- Select Project settings > Service connections.
  [image]
- Select + New service connection, select the type of service
  connection that you need, and then select Next.
  [image]

[image]

- Choose Service Principal (manual), and Next

[image]

- Enter the parameters for the service connection. The list of parameters differs for each type of service connection. For more information, see the list of service connection types and associated parameters.
- Select Save to create the connection.

[image]

- Validate the connection, once it's created and parameters are entered. The validation link uses a REST call to the external service with the information that you entered, and indicates whether the call succeeded.

Then, finally, once you've created your service connection, complete the following steps to use it.

- Copy the connection name into your code as the azureSubscription (or the equivalent connection name) value.

[image]

- Authorize the service connection using one of the following techniques:
  To authorize any pipeline to use the service connection, go to Azure Pipelines, open the Settings page, select Service connections, and enable the setting Allow all pipelines to use this connection option for the connection.
- To authorize a service connection for a specific pipeline, open the pipeline by selecting Edit and queue a build manually. You see a resource authorization error and an "Authorize resources" action on the error. Choose this action to explicitly add the pipeline as an authorized user of the service connection.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-11.3.0